# Selecting updated timestamp using XPath

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

XPath noob question:
I have an HTML file that contains

`<p class="postinginfo">Updated: <time datetime="2013-11-21T12:39:50-0600">2013-11-21, 12:39PM CST</time></p>`

`<p class="postinginfo">Posted: <time datetime="2013-11-20T12:39:50-0600">2013-11-20, 12:39PM CST</time></p>`

I'm trying to extract the time using C# and HtmlAgilityPack

```
var htmldocs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class=\"postinginfo\"]Updated:/text()");
```

This did not work.  Reading through the XPath tutorial on w3schools.com it wasn't obvious how the functions should be used.  I'd appreciate some guidance from a more experienced XPath user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you install firefox+firebug+firepath to test xpath expression.
Try this xpath:

```
//p[@class='postinginfo' and contains(., 'Updated:')]/time/@datetime
```

Comment: Thanks, but when ... contains(., 'Updated:' ... is added the returned htmldocs is 'null'.  I added a line to the HTML code in the question to help clarify what I'm  trying to do.  (BTW- When I installed firefox, it loaded a couple undesired extensions to both firefox and chrome even though I specifically declined them during installation!)

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly.  In my 'live test' case the web server delivered a web page that didn't have an element that contained 'Updated' -- only and element that contained "Posted" existed. +1